# PageSpeed recommends to minimize Facebook redirects

Tags: optimization, https, facebook-javascript-sdk, http-redirect, pagespeed

I'm using Google's Pagespeed to optimize my website. This is one of the recommendations:

[image]

Basically, the facebook script is being called as **http** and then redirected to the **https** version of it.

This is Facebook's code, inserted before `</body>`

```
<script>
//facebook
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I tried changing the `js.src = "//...` to `js.src = "https://..."` but the problem is still happening. Any ideas? Thanks!